# Shell script for copying csv files to postgres database is changing table name to lowercase and causing it to fail

Tags: postgresql, shell, csv

I have a shell script to upload a bunch of .csv files to a postgres database.

```
#!/bin/zsh

for f in csvs/*.csv
do
    mytable=$(basename "$f" .csv)
    psql -d mydb --user=ian -c "copy $mytable from '$f' delimiter ',' csv header;" 
done
```

The csv files look like `B02001.csv`, `B99211.csv` and so on, and the tables are named like `B02001`, `B99211` to match the csv files, but when I run the script I get the error

```
ERROR:  relation "b02001" does not exist
```

Somehow the `$mytable` variable must be getting turned to lowercase and causing the statement to fail. What is causing that?

Comment: If the table name is not double quoted("B02001") it will be folded to lower case. See here [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) 'Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. '

Comment: Wrapping the `$mytable` variable in quotes causes the error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'B08007'"
LINE 1: copy 'B08007' from 'csvs2/B08007.csv' delimiter ',' csv head...`

Comment: It needs to be `"B08007"` no nested  single quotes.

Comment: I'm new to postgres, I'm migrating this database from mysql. Should I rename the tables to lowercase to make it easier and more conventional? like `b02001`. It's not a problem to do.

Comment: It would make things easier. The SQL standard says unquoted names(identifiers) will be folded to upper case, Postgres deviates from this and goes the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to quote the name, OR expect it to be lower.

From [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) -

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)

Try

```
"copy \"$mytable\" from '$f' delimiter ',' csv header;"
```

Comment: This is assuming that the file names ARE capitals ... Run the script with the -x option to see the intermediate results ... e.g. `zsh -x yourscript.zsh ARGS`

Comment: Putting escaped quotes around the $f returns  `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""csvs/B99283.csv""
LINE 1: copy B99283 from "csvs/B99283.csv" delimiter ',' csv header...`

Comment: Running it with -x shows `psql -d acs --user=ian -c 'copy B23025 from '\''csvs/B23025.csv'\'' delimiter '\'','\'' csv header;'
ERROR:  relation "b23025" does not exist`

Comment: It worked when I put escaped quotes around `$mytable` like `\"$mytable\"` and also use `\copy` instead of `copy` for some reason. If you will edit your answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @ian-campbell - yes - do what I meant not what I wrote sorry